# Android, View lifecycle and restore

Tags: android, view, lifecycle, restore

I has a view that is create by

```
this.vehicleListUI = new GameUIVehicleList();
this.vehicleListUI.attachGameEngine(myGameEngine);
```

This work fin unto the android destroy and restore the view.
The Android can recreate the view by use the empty constructor, 
but my problem is for this `GameUIVehicleList` will work I most also have the `myGameEngine`
object set to the `GameUIVehicleList`

The `myGameEngine` is not Serializable and can't be this to ( Is a part of UI )

Exist this a way to restore my View fully by reattach the `myGameEngine` object
to a create view.
This will also be good for enable a lot of "new GameUIVehicleList()" into a XML layout file.

**EDIT:**

I don't know if this is to some help but way I has this problem from begin is 
I use a `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` and this keep to destroy and recreate
my View object. I can also fix this by override some method in `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` that is invoke while `FragmentActivity` is recreate/crate a fragment and for this set the need value from my Activity that hold the need data.

Comment: you mist likely do not need `this.` in your code.

Comment: True WebnetMobile.com but I think the code is more clearly if this object is class variable also.

Comment: Sure, do as you like (I personally prefix global scope variable with `m` as many others do on this platform). It was just a note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destroying and re-creation of Activity (and views) usually happens on configuration change (most often screen orientation change). You may want to check if [this article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) helps and [onRetainNonconfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29)/`setRetainInstance()` would not be the cure for your problems.

Comment: wow, this would have saved a lot of time. thanks, just learned something.

Answer (score 0):

If `myGameEngine` is not `Serializable` or `Parcelable`, I do not believe it is possible to do this reliably.

However if it is ok, for `myGameEngine` to sometimes not be recovered you can extend the `Application` class with your own custom `MyApplication` class which contains the variable `myGameEngine` then in your `onCreate` you can get the `myGameEngine` that saved in your application context.

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) this.getApplicationContext();
this.vehicleListUI.attachGameEngine(app.myGameEngine);
```

Comment: The problem is the `myGameEngine` always most be reachable from the View object. Base on the View don't know what data to show and most always registry to some observer that `myGameEngine` hold.